# Where to specify FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, focus

I have checked and tried most of the answers involving this question but could not get it working.  I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvDataBinding" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

In order to remove the dotted ("marching ants") border around ListView items, I tried adding `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"` to the TextBlock element, to the WrapPanel and to the ListView.  None of them worked.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dotted line is for **`ListViewItem`** so you have to set that null for ListViewItem which you can do in **`ItemContainerStyle`**:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You tried to help me out in an earlier question, but I had to accept another answer then, so I am glad that this time, I am able to mark this one as the answer.